# Why when i try to scrape multiple pages I can not get all the text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrape

I am trying to scrape multiple imsdb pages to get the movie scripts to create a dataset of movie scripts.
I wrote this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import requests       #to send the request to the URL
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np  # to count the values (in our case)
import selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
  
from time import sleep
from random import randint


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

scriptsList=[]
newScript=[]
titles=[]
movie_titles = pd.read_csv("movies.csv")
l=0;
url_list=[]


for index,row in movie_titles.iterrows():
    movieString=movie_titles.loc[index]["title"]
    count=0
    #print(row)
    #assigning the URL with variable name url
    movieString=movie_titles.loc[index]["title"]
    movieString=str(movieString)
    titles.append(movieString)
    movieString=movieString.replace(" ", "")
    url = 'https://imsdb.com/scripts/'+movieString+'.html'
    url_list.append(url)

for i in url_list:
      # Target URL
  driver.get(url)
  
  # print(driver.title)
  
  # Printing the whole body text
  jt=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body").text
  jt = jt.strip('\n')
  jt = jt.strip('\t')
  print(jt)
  scriptsList.append(jt)

  # Closing the driver
driver.close()

scripts_DF = pd.DataFrame({'title': titles, 'Script': scriptsList})
scripts_DF.to_csv('NewScripts6.csv')'''
```

but the code doesn't print all the text it only prints this

```
 ALL SCRIPTS





Writers :
Genres :


User Comments



Back to IMSDb





Index    |    Submit    |    Link to IMSDb    |    Disclaimer    |    Privacy policy    |    Contact
The Internet Movie Script Database (IMSDb)

The web's largest
movie script resource!

Search IMSDb

Alphabetical
# A B C D E F G H
I J K L M N O P Q
R S T U V W X Y Z

Genre
Action Adventure Animation
Comedy Crime Drama
Family Fantasy Film-Noir
Horror Musical Mystery
Romance Sci-Fi Short
Thriller War Western
```

I also wrote this code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import requests       #to send the request to the URL
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np  # to count the values (in our case)
import selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


# Importing necessary modules
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
  
# WebDriver Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  
# Target URL
#driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/competitive-programming-a-complete-guide/")

driver.get("https://imsdb.com/scripts/Toy-Story.html")

# print(driver.title)
  
# Printing the whole body text
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body").text)
  
# Closing the driver
driver.close()
```

this code prints all the  text of the website can anyone help me to scrape multiple pages and get all the text from them.I think i need to add time delays to the program because the site can not handle so many requests

Comment: Could you clarify what your desired output is? Where do you want to pull the movie scripts from?

Answer (score 0):

With this code to me print all text

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://imsdb.com/Movie%20Scripts/Joker%20Script.html")
jt = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body").text
print(jt)
```

Comment: I want to get the script of every movie on imsdb not only one movie

Comment: ok, in this case and using your code
'
for i in url_list:
      # Target URL
        driver.get(i)
        jt = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body").text
        print(jt)
'

Comment: This code doesn't print all the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
list=["Cable%20Guy%20Script","Joker%20Script","Capote%20Script"]


for film in list:
 driver.get("https://imsdb.com/Movie%20Scripts/"+film+".html")
 jt = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body").text
 print(jt.strip('\n').strip('\t'))
```

the output is so long, so I attach a piece

```
Capote Script
IMSDb opinion
 None available

IMSDb rating
 Not available
Average user rating
 None available

Writers
  Dan Futterman

Genres
 Crime
Drama

Movie Release Date : February 2006

Read "Capote" Script

User Comments for Capote
```

Add your own comment
*Name: E-mail:

Comment: karaldhmhtrhs3@gmail.com  i want the text from this page https://imsdb.com/scripts/Thor-Ragnarok.html for example i want the script but i can not get it.Thanks for helping

Comment: you need to use

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://imsdb.com/scripts/Thor-Ragnarok.html")
jt = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//*[@class='scrtext']").text
print(jt)`